# How to implement a 'AddToFavorites' button on an win8 app

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, microsoft-metro, application-bar

I am developing an app on win8 and would like to add an 'AddToFavorites' button on the application bar, so that the user can select his favorites/bookmarks and place them to this. I have added this button to the application bar but the button does not perform any action when clicked.

Currently what I have done is

```
    private async void Favorite_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

         if (SampleDataSource.GetGroup("Favorite").Items.Count != 0)
        {
            if (this.pageTitle.Text != "Favorite")
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage),                         SampleDataSource.GetGroup("Favorite").Items[0].UniqueId);
        }
        else
        {
            await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("You haven't marked any favorites.").ShowAsync();

        }
    }
```

But I dont see this functionality working. Any of your suggestions would be of great help to me. It is a Windows8 Metro style C#/XAML App. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need to clarify your question. As it is written we have no idea what you mean by "getting it working".

Comment: I meant that, when the user clicks on the favorites button, nothing happens, there is no action taking place.

Comment: On the itemviewpage, the user should be able to click a page as his fav/unfav at any time. is it possible?

Comment: I assume you are sure that this handler gets called and the 'Navigate' method gets called but nothing happens. right?
Have you tried using RunAsync?
       Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                            () => this.Frame.Navigate(typeof...

Comment: True that 'navigate' method gets called but nothing happens. Now, I tried giving only `if (itemListView.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                Favorite.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                Favorite.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            } `  In this case, when an item is clicked, favorite button gets collapsed but does not re-appear when another item in the same page gets clicked again.

Comment: And also             `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), SampleDataSource.GetGroup("Favorite").Items[0].UniqueId);  
            });

            var ignored = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {

            });`  dint make any difference

Comment: Edited the code a litle bit to see if it works, but no use!    `var  y = this.itemListView.SelectedItems;
 if (this.itemListView.Visibility ==   Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed)
 {
 y = this.itemListView.SelectedItems;
 }
  foreach (var x in y)
  {
   SampleDataItem i = x as SampleDataItem;
   var f = SampleDataSource.GetGroup("");
                
            if (!SampleDataSource.FavoriteManager.isFavorite(int.Parse(i.UniqueId)))
                    await SampleDataSource.addToGroupByNum(int.Parse(i.UniqueId), f);

           SampleDataSource.FavoriteManager.WriteFavs();
            }`